# Next.js Export - Custom Image Loader Not Working

Tags: javascript, deployment, next.js

I'm trying to build and export my Next.JS project, and I'm stuck with Image Optimization error while exporting.

I've created a custom loader, creating a file `/services/imageLoader.js` with the following content:

```js
export default function LocalImageLoader({src, width, quality}) {
    var fileName = src.split("/").pop();
    return `./_next/static/media/${fileName}`;
}
```

And, inside all my pages where I used the next/image component, I've added the `loader` attribute to , pointing to my LocalImageLoader funcion, this way:

```js
import LocalImageLoader from '../services/imageLoader';
import logoImage from '../resources/images/logo.png';

// boring stuff here
<Image loader={LocalImageLoader} src={logoImage} alt="Logo" className="img-fluid" />
// more boring stuff here
```

After that, everytime I try to run `npm run export` (I've set up the export script in my package.json, that runs `next build && next export`), and the following error comes in my screen:

```
Error: Image Optimization using Next.js' default loader is not compatible with `next export`.
  Possible solutions:
    - Use `next start` to run a server, which includes the Image Optimization API.
    - Use any provider which supports Image Optimization (like Vercel).
    - Configure a third-party loader in `next.config.js`.
    - Use the `loader` prop for `next/image`.
  Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/export-image-api
    at /home/raphael/Projects/Next/learning/testProject/node_modules/next/dist/export/index.js:256:23
    at async Span.traceAsyncFn (/home/raphael/Projects/Next/learning/testProject/node_modules/next/dist/trace/trace.js:74:20)
```

Can someone say me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to add your custom loader to `next.config.js`. You will need to do something like in snippet below. In case if you won't succeed there are available loaders, because default loader won't work when you export.

```
module.exports = {
  images: {
    loader: 'custom',
    path: 'https://example.com/myaccount/',
  },
}
```

More info here: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/image#loader-configuration